# vote-down privileges explanation on meta gives 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

Trying to vote down on a meta site prior to the 125 rep level gives an error message with a link to *https://meta.{ site }.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down*, which gives a 404.

(The bug is the 404, not the error, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we've removed all other instances of this in the UI, we'll kick this case up to the parent site so users who are interested can get a full privilege explanation.  This will go into effect next build.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges and click "vote down" you come to 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down which works fine for me.

---

The meta.stackoverflow.com (aka meta.stackexchange.com) is an own site "independent" from stackoverflow.com, while all meta.{site}.stackexchange.com sites are bundled with their main site. They seem to have no `/privileges` page at all, so not just 'vote-down' is affected. Simply go to {site}.stackexchange.com/privileges or {site}.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down instead.

Comment: I can reproduce it on meta.cooking though - MSO is probably different.

Comment: @Rup: The difference is that meta.stackoverflow.com (aka meta.stackexchange.com) is an own site "independent" from stackoverflow.com, while all meta.{site}.sx sites are bundled with their main site. They seem to have no `/privileges` page at all, not just 'vote-down' is effected.

Comment: I didn't bother looking for any of the other privilege pages.  The 404 is still a bug - either the link should be to the primary site's page, or it should work.

Comment: @Tony: I agree.